# Kann "Zur A, bei B und bei C" an der ersten Position eines Satzes stehen?

Tags: word-order

In dieser Frage geht es um den folgenden Satz aus *Deutsche Grammatik einfach, kompakt und übersichtlich* von Heike Pahlow.

> Zur Negation von Verben, bei Nomen mit bestimmtem Artikel und bei Pronomen verwenden wir in negativen Sätzen *nicht*.

**FRAGE**

1. Steht *verwenden* an der zweiten Position des Satzes?
2. Wenn ja zu 1, steht an der ersten Position das gesamte *Zur Negation von Verben, bei Nomen mit bestimmtem Artikel und bei Pronomen*?
3. Kann man für die Wortstellung mit Kommas und ohne Konjunktion beliebig viele Satzglieder in einem Element vereinigen?  Zum Beispiel, *Zur A, bei B, an C, für D*?
4. Wenn nein zu 1, was (welche grammatische Regel) erlaubt *verwenden* (das finite Verb), an einer anderen Position als der zweiten zu stehen?
5. Ist es richtig, *Wenn ja zu 1, steht...* zu sagen?  Frage 2 ist eine Entscheidungsfrage, bei welcher das finite Verb an erster Position stehen muss, aber *steht* steht an zweiter Position.

Comment: *Ein Esel, ein Hund, eine Katze und ein Hahn stehen in Riga.* An erster Stelle steht eine Aufzählung, an zweiter das Verb.

Comment: Die stehen kurz vor Bremen!

Comment: @äüö Riga und Bremen sind Partnerstädte. Die Hanse lässt grüßen ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ja
2. Ja
3. Ja, aber irgendwann wird der Satz dann unverständlich. Das ist erlaubt, sollte aber vermeiden werden.
4. -
5. Es tut mir leid, ich verstehe diese Frage nicht.

---

Ich gebe dir ein anderes Beispiel:

> Ich sehe Autos und Bäume

Darin sind enthalten:

- An Position 1: das Subjekt

  - ich
- An Position 2: das Prädikat

  - sehe
- An Position 3: ein Objekt (in diesem Fall ein Akkusativobjekt)

  - Autos und Bäume

> [**Ich**]<sub>Subjekt</sub> [**sehe**]<sub>Prädikat</sub> [**Autos und Bäume**]<sub>Objekt</sub>.

In der deutschen Sprache sind, anders als z.B. in der englischen, die grammatischen Funktionen an den Beugungen der verschiedenen Fälle zu erkennen. Es ist daher möglich, die Reihenfolge der Bestandteile zu verändern. Allerdings muss das Prädikat bei Aussagesätzen immer an Position 2 stehen. Das erlaubt auch diese Reihenfolge:

- An Position 1: Objekt

  - Autos und Bäume
- An Position 2: Prädikat

  - sehe
- An Position 3: Subjekt

  - ich

Also:

> Autos und Bäume sehe ich.
>   [**Autos und Bäume**]<sub>Objekt</sub> [**sehe**]<sub>Prädikat</sub> [**ich**]<sub>Subjekt</sub>.

Das ist ein ganz normaler und völlig korrekter deutscher Satz.

Das Objekt in diesem Beispiel ist eine Aufzählung. Diese kann man beliebig erweitern, etwa so:

> Ich sehe Autos, Bäume, Wolken, Menschen, Fahrräder, ein Lebensmittelgeschäft, das aber gerade geschlossen hat, ein kleines Café und ein Buchgeschäft.
>
> [**Ich**]<sub>Subjekt</sub> [**sehe**]<sub>Prädikat</sub> [**Autos, Bäume, Wolken, Menschen, Fahrräder, ein Lebensmittelgeschäft, das aber gerade geschlossen hat, ein kleines Café und ein Buchgeschäft**]<sub>Objekt</sub>.

Das Objekt ist jetzt deutlich länger als vorher, aber noch immer nur genau ein einzige Objekt:

> Autos, Bäume, Wolken, Menschen, Fahrräder, ein Lebensmittelgeschäft, das aber gerade geschlossen hat, ein kleines Café und ein Buchgeschäft

Und dieses eine Objekt kann man an Position 1 stellen:

> Autos, Bäume, Wolken, Menschen, Fahrräder, ein Lebensmittelgeschäft, das aber gerade geschlossen hat, ein kleines Café und ein Buchgeschäft sehe ich.
>
> [**Autos, Bäume, Wolken, Menschen, Fahrräder, ein Lebensmittelgeschäft, das aber gerade geschlossen hat, ein kleines Café und ein Buchgeschäft**]<sub>Objekt</sub> [**sehe**]<sub>Prädikat</sub> [**ich**]<sub>Subjekt</sub>.

Auch das ist ein völlig korrekter deutscher Satz, so wie auch dein Beispielsatz.

> [**Zur Negation von Verben, bei Nomen mit bestimmtem Artikel und bei Pronomen**]<sub>Objekt</sub> [**verwenden**]<sub>Prädikat</sub> [**wir**]<sub>Subjekt</sub> [**in negativen Sätzen**]<sub>Objekt</sub> [**»nicht«**]<sub>Objekt</sub>.

Comment: "Autos sehe ich und Bäume" geht übrigens auch prima ;)

Comment: @tofro Wobei man da argumentieren kann, dass es sich um zwei mit der Konjunktion *und* verbundene Sätze handelt, wobei im zweiten die Dopplungen weggelassen wurden ;)

Comment: @Jan: Tofros Argument hat mich ganz schön zum Nachdenken gebracht, aber ich glaube, du hast die Lösung gefunden. Wenn man die Definition von »Satz« etwas lockerer fasst, so dass auch die wichtigsten Variationen der Umgangssprache abgebildet werden, dann sind auch zwei getrennte Sätze möglich, gerne mit einer kurzen Pause zwischen den beiden Sätzen: »Ich sehe Autos. - Und Bäume.«

Answer (score 2):

> Zur Negation von Verben, bei Nomen mit bestimmtem Artikel und bei
>   Pronomen verwenden wir in negativen Sätzen nicht.

Ersetzt man die Präpostionalobjekte durch Fragewörter, sind die Antworten auf die **Fragen 1** und **2** klar: "verwenden" steht an der zweiten Position, alles davor zusammen an der ersten Position:

Wozu und wobei verwenden wir....?

Zu **Frage 3**: Theoretisch kann man tatsächlich beliebig viele Elemente verbinden, die auch Relativsätze beinhalten können. Das ist jedoch nicht zu empfehlen, wenn man als Autor (welcher Textsorte auch immer) gelesen und verstanden werden möchte.

Zu **Frage 5**: Die Formulierung deiner Frage
*"Wenn ja zu 1, steht...."*
ist grammatikalisch nicht richtig, da der Nebensatz nicht vollständig ist. Korrekt müsste es beispielsweise heißen:

> Wenn Frage 1 bejaht wird, steht dann...?